# Which takes precedence: reading the .htaccess or a 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following lines in my .htaccess file:

```
    #redirect A
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/partners/$1/index.shtml -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /partners/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

These lines check for the existence of a directory and redirects the user if it exists.

```
    #redirect B
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/partners/$1/index.shtml !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /partners/default.php?code=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Similarly, these lines check for the non-existence of a directory and redirect the user somewhere else if the directory isn't found.

Here's what's happening: say I visit `www.example.com/andyf` and the `andyf` folder doesn't exist in the `partners` directory, then I'm taken to `www.example.com/partners/default.php?code=andyf`

So far, so good.

However, if the `andyf` directory is created later I'm still taken to the `default.php` page, even though the correct directory exists now. This is down to the 301 redirect which has been put in place.

What confuses me is that if the .htaccess file is [read on every request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess#Advantages) then why isn't redirect A overwriting redirect B? Or is the 301 redirect taking place, as I suspect, before the .htaccess file is read?

Comment: As an aside, I don't think that redirect B should be a 301 redirect (most likely should be a 307) but this is the situation I've got myself into and now I'm interested in the outcome.

Comment: when you clear your browser cache, do you still get the same result ?

Comment: If I clear the cache from within the browser then it doesn't seem to forget the 301s. However if I hit the Clear Cache button in Fiddler it seems to forget them successfully - I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: then it is just a matter of cache, not htaccess.

Comment: OK, thanks. So is that the answer? That the cache is checked and acted upon before the .htaccess file is? If you write up your comment as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is just a matter of cache, if you clear your cache it will work as expected.